# How do I manage postings in discussions on an ongoing complex question

Tags: discussion, support

My question on [wormhole time machines](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2865/wormholes-time-machines-for-experts-in-gr-maths) is getting into complicated discussions. Comments are too short for responses (and don't support e.g. images, which I intend to use for clarification) and extending the original questions/answers loses continuity of discussion. [I extended my question to deal with various comments & Lubos Motl's answer; Lubos has expanded his answer... I now need to address the Lubos Expansion in detail...]

How should I proceed? TIA, Julian

Comment: Break it up into smaller, manageable pieces, each of which could be a separate question on its own. It is clear that your question deals with several issues, not just one, so this should be possible.

Comment: The problem is that you really need to understand general relativity moderately well to understand wormhole time machines, and that this forum is not a good system to run a tutorial on general relativity.

Answer (score 6):

Do not ask such questions; they are just unmanageable in Q&A system. Ask questions that can get simple, definite answers and move discussions to chat (for instance propose relevant paper for Journal Club) and other places.